# Creating android 3d game with Android Studio and Unity

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, firebase

I'm trying to create a TBS game with an isometric view for android. I began with Android Studio and I've already designed core parts of the UI including login, registration, authentication, and menus. I'm now trying to create the actual game and I've discovered that in order to make a 3d game, the only reasonably efficient path is to create the game from an engine like Unity3d. Is this true? How can I keep the progress I've already made while doing this? For example, is there a way I can launch and instance of the Unity game and pass the variables needed, while the rest of the app is made using Android Studio? Unity uses C# and I'd prefer Java, is there a way around this? The authentication and user information currently uses Firebase, if I need to rebuild this app in Unity, how can I use Firebase? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use Android's `UI` to load Unity game with making it a plugin. It is possible but as a beginner,it would be hard for you to set it up.  Also, after all the hard-work, your game will only work on Android because the `UI` is made in Android. I suggest you learn C#. You can't run from it when working with Unity. Since you know Java, it should be a piece of cake to learn C#. http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting For `UI` http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/58337
That is the firebase API that you can use within Unity,
I do also believe that Unity has some features available for UI so you should be able to build it completely within Unity. Also, you can write the scripts in C#, JavaScript but I don't believe Unity supports Java for scripting out of the box.

- Edit

I also just realized, C# is pretty similar to Java, you should really like it.